# Thermal conductivity in 2D

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm working on a heat conduction problem on a surface which can be approximated as a thin, flat plate. The heat equation in terms of temperature has the form

$\frac{dT}{dt}=k \nabla^2 T$

Is there an expression for $k$ that can be derived from either the 1D thermal conductivity or the 3D thermal diffusivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the same coefficient k in all cases assuming the system is isotropic. The units of both sides of the equation are the same in any case. In other words, you would use the same $k$ in all dimensions